# returning bool value to main c++ always returning true regardless of answer

Tags: c++, function

Im new to programming and I seem to have a problem returning the finalResult variable, every time I pass it back to main it returns true regardless of the answer being true or false but if I output in the second function I get the right answer, is it something to do with the "*result"?

The question I received from my teacher was as follows...

"A function HasValue that may be passed a reference to an array, the size of the array and a
search value. The function should return true if the search value exists in the array"

so I wrote this,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
bool HasValue(int number, long length, int arr[], bool finalResult);
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    int num, arr[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    bool result;
    auto array_length = end(arr) - begin(arr); //size of array
    cout << "enter number: ";
    cin >> num;
    HasValue(num, array_length, arr, result);
    cout << result << "\n";

    return 0;
}
bool HasValue(int number, long length, int arr[], bool finalResult)
{

    int* end = arr + length;
    int* result = find(arr, end, number);
    if (result != end)
        finalResult = true;
    else
        finalResult = false;

    return finalResult;
}
```

I am probably doing something really silly but I cant spot it, any help is much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: You did something really silly... you didn't set `result` to anything.

Comment: Here is the entire `HasValue` function :  `return std::find(arr, arr + length, number) != array + length;`

Comment: thank you, id didn't realise i had to, i thought it would default as "0"

Comment: ***i thought it would default as "0"*** Local variables don't get initialized by the compiler. You need to initialize them. Your compiler should have warned about an uninitialized variable access.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `HasValue` function does nothing with the value of `finalResult` passed to it (which I guess it good since you pass an indeterminate value). And your call site doesn't do anything with the value `HasValue` returned. Either use the return falue of `HasValue` or pass `finalResult` by reference.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, it works perfect, i passed it by reference